# Format Time String RDLC

Tags: rdlc, time-format

I can not get the 24 hour time to convert to 12 hour time format.

I have a Time Column in my RDLC report which displays times in 24 hour clock (17:00:00) (HH:mm:ss)

To display them in a 12 hour time format, I have tried to right-clicked the Textbox -> Text Box Properties -> Number -> Custom and entered a time format for a 12 hour clock "hh:mm:ss tt" (05:00:00 PM is what I expected)

I have also tried the provided Time formats and nothing seems to change my 24 hour time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to convert this to a CDATE for the format to take place.

Answer (score -1):

Your format is right. Try like this - right click on text box - choose expression and your format is write in expression like this `Format(Now,"dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt")`:

[image]